# Is possible to use multiple retrofit API

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2. I need to use 2 different Rest API, because they have different base URL, headers and cookies.

```
public class RestClient {

private static IRestApi REST_CLIENT;

static {
    setupRestClient();
}

public static IRestApi get() {
    return REST_CLIENT;
}

private static void setupRestClient() {

    Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      //add some cookies & headers
        }
    };

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(GenericConstants.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(GenericConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(GenericConstants.BASE_ENDPOINT_INSTAGRAM)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(IRestApi.class);
    }
}
```

I am using it like so:

```
Call<Obj> call = RestClient.get().myMethod(params);
```

I want to create 2 clases like this, because I have 2 types of requests, 1 with headers and cookies and one plain, is this possible?

Comment: why can't you use a singleton class?\

Answer (score 1):

you can create method of retrofit url like

```
public Retrofit getAdapter(String url){
      Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

      return retrofit;
}
```

Use this adapter wherever you want.

Comment: return statement?

Comment: thanks @Pawan for mark return issue. I updated my answer.